# Unable to create a bootable partition on NVME drive

Tags: windows, partitioning, nvme, diskpart

[image]

[Booting Windows off M.2 NVMe doesn’t work even though it is recognized by the BIOS on a dual boot machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1704309/booting-windows-off-m-2-nvme-doesn-t-work-even-though-it-is-recognized-by-the-bi/1777525?noredirect=1#comment2773323_1777525)

I was delighted when I found the above answer explaining how to create a boot partition, as this is exactly the problem I am having. However, in diskpart I get the message diskpart has encountered and error the service cannot be started either because it's disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it. Can anyone offer any advice please?

[image: On screen error][disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph5Ii.jpg)

Update
Thank you for the help so far with this issue. I have now successfully created a boot partition and ( I think) added the files, but only the original Windows Boot Manager is recognised in the Bios. Please help me proceed so I can remove my old SSD

[enter image description here][5][screen shot od disk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHRPa.jpg)

[Screen shot of BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph5Ii.jpg)

Comment: I think you should show the exact error / output, and add the output of `list disk` too.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide screenshots of the error, and that if your partitions, so your question contains the necessary information to answer your question

Comment: Evidently you have disabled service(s) that are necessary to the shrinking task. As the message says, there should be an entry in the System Event Log with details.

Comment: Thanks Kreemoweet you were right. I have edited the post as have moved on, but not yet succeeded